# Display PDF file in Cordova WP8 app

Tags: cordova, pdf, windows-phone-8

How can I show a PDF file in Cordova WP8 app? I am using the [InAppBrowser plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) to display a PDF file but it gives this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.ni.dll
```

I am calling the function

```
window.open(<URL-to-PDF>, '_system');
```

The URL is working in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Cordova Document Viewer Plugin
https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

Answer (score 0):

By using the [Cordova Document Viewer Plugin](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer) you easily can achieve this functioning.The purpose of the plugin is to create an platform independent javascript interface for Cordova based mobile applications to view different document types by using native viewer components.To install the plugin run this command in your project directory

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer.git --save
```

--save flag automatically save the plugin in your config.xml file.
The plugin and its methods are not available before the deviceready event has been fired.

```
SitewaertsDocumentViewer.canViewDocument(
    url, contentType, options, onPossible, onMissingApp, onImpossible,
```

onError);

onPossible

```
function(){
  window.console.log('document can be shown');
  //e.g. track document usage
}
```

onMissingApp

```
function(appId, installer)
{
    if(confirm("Do you want to install the free PDF Viewer App "
            + appId + " for Android?"))
    {
        installer();
    }
}
```

onImpossible

```
function(){
  window.console.log('document cannot be shown');
  //e.g. track document usage
}
```

onError

```
function(error){
  window.console.log(error);
  alert("Sorry! Cannot show document.");
}
```

Open a Document File

```
SitewaertsDocumentViewer.viewDocument(
    url, mimeType, options, onShow, onClose, onMissingApp, onError);
```

onShow

```
function(){
  window.console.log('document shown');
  //e.g. track document usage
}
```

onClose

```
function(){
  window.console.log('document closed');
  //e.g. remove temp files
}
```

onMissingApp

```
function(id, installer)
{
    if(confirm("Do you want to install the free PDF Viewer App "
            + appId + " for Android?"))
    {
        installer();
    }
}
```

onError

```
function(error){
  window.console.log(error);
  alert("Sorry! Cannot view document.");
}
```